# Java Rounding two digits after decimal point without Math.round, BigDecimal, etc

Tags: java, math, rounding

Hay,

I want to round a number two digits after the decimal point only by using this mathematic formula:
[image: Math formula]

For example the number **831.38849** should be rounded to 831.39 and printed out. I have tried something like this, but it didn't work: **0.01 * (100 * number + 0.5)**

I know that similar questions have been asked before, but I'm not allowed to use all the fancy and easy stuff for this task like **Math.round**, **BigDecimal**, etc

Comment: Convert to a String and then search for `.` and then substring based upon that

Comment: `⌊ ⌋` are math symbols for `floor()` operation, so perhaps your attempt is not working because you ignored that part of the formula!!! --- If you want to follow mathematic formulas, learn to read them right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, the fancy part is handled by casting your floating point number to an integral value.  You want to eliminate the portion two places to the right of the decimal, so you first multiply it by 100 to shift the decimal, add the 0.5 to round up anything 0.5 or higher, cast to an int (or a long) to truncate it, then divide by 100 to shift the decimal point back.

[Edit -- Adding condition to handle negatives, so it meets definition of "floor".]

```
double original_number = 831.38849;
double rounded_number = (original_number >= 0) 
   ? ((long) (original_number * 100 + 0.5)) / 100.0
   : ((long) (original_number * 100 - 0.5)) / 100.0;
```

Comment: Perhaps [`Math.floor()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#floor-double-) would be better than casting to `long`, to prevent numeric overflow. --- Besides, or more importantly, the `⌊ ⌋` math symbols actually means `floor()`, and casting to `long` is a *truncation* operation, not a *floor* operation.

Comment: The OP is trying to avoid any predefined functions.

Comment: No, OP is trying to implement the displayed mathematic formula to implement rounding, and don't want to use the `round()` method instead of the formula. The mathematic formula uses a *floor* operation, so the correct implementation of that **formula**, is to use `floor()`.

Comment: I suppose you're right.  If he's not allowed to use all the "fancy and easy stuff for this task like Math.round()...", then he'll have to come up with a proper equivalent to Math.floor(), and the version I gave would work only for positive numbers.

Comment: I agree that it's not clear from the question whether `Math.floor()` is "allowed".  Perhaps somebody should post an answer that uses `Math.floor()`, so that both techniques are on display.

Comment: @DawoodsaysreinstateMonica [Done](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58966702/5221149)

Comment: Also, @phatfingers, it might be worth noting in your answer that it doesn't quite work for negative numbers, because the question didn't ask for something that was restricted to positive numbers.  Alternatively, of course, you could fix it.

Comment: Awesome!  Thanks.

Comment: I hope I'm doing this correctly by replying here but I'm not not allowed to use Math.floor(). Sorry if I might have worded that weird. Thank you very much phatfingers, your answer helped me!

Comment: Your welcome-- although much of the credit really goes to Andreas for pointing out that truncating alone doesn't fully meet the definition of a floor.

Answer (score 2):

`⌊ ⌋` are math symbols for the floor function<sup>[1](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/FloorFunction.html), [2](https://www.mathsisfun.com/sets/function-floor-ceiling.html), [3](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floor_and_ceiling_functions)</sup>

So the correct implementation of the mathematic formula
[image: formula image]
is the following Java code:

```java
Math.floor(100d * number + 0.5) / 100d
```

<sup>*Note:* `100d` can also be written `100.0`, `100.`, or simply `100`  (assuming `number` is a `double`)</sup>